# Mongoose save function is not working and returns empty {} object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on creating Auth API using Mongo and Nodejs. I have done the initial part. But when i hit the register API, it returns an empty object. Here's my scheme:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 6,
        max: 255
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 255,
        min: 6
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 1024,
        min: 6
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

And here's where the request is being sent:

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../model/User');

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    try{
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        res.send(savedUser);
    }catch(err){
        res.status(400).send(err);
    }
})


module.exports = router;
```

Now the `user.save` is not working for some reason. Not sure what i'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It automatically gets the _id when it creates an object from the User Scheme.So it would be pointless to reassign

```js
try{
    await user.save();
    res.send(user);
}catch(err){
    res.status(400).send(err);
}
```